# Kinect or Asus for a movement base

Tags: ros, kinect, xtion, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody.

I am developing a mobile base with wheels for a robot and I am thinking different sensors for calculate distances, track people and avoid obstacles.

I found two alternatives: Kinect for Windows (I think that its better that Kinect 360 but I dont know exactly) and Asus Xtion PRO LIVE.

Searching in the web, I dont found a lot of differences between the two: Asus have USB power supply and better RGM image and Kinect are more complet, with a lot of functions (tracking skelletons, near mode, ...) but I dont know what it will be better to my work.

Anyone knows which is better or which fits better with my project?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105571/kinect-or-asus-for-a-movement-base/) by [elseine](https://answers.ros.org/users/9251/elseine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, AFAIK there is a difference between Kinect and Kinect for Windows regarding driver support and so on. Be aware of that.

Second, if comparing Kinect and Asus Xtion Pro Live: They are essentially the same. The internal hardware is the same and driver and software support are also the same. The main difference is that the Xtion is USB powered, while the Kinect needs an additional 12V power supply. In addition the Kinect is larger.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elseine](https://answers.ros.org/users/9251/elseine/) on 2013-11-28**:
So, really, its the same except that the Kinect is 12V powered and Asus is USB no? They have the same features (skeleton tracking, measure depth and distances, etc... right?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-28**:
Software and sensors are the same.

**Comment by [stevej_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/24516/stevej_80/) on 2015-10-25**:
Hello, I know this thread is old but I have 1 question regarding the same topic. I want to use Asus with gmapping to do SLAM. I prefer the minimum bells and whistles, so does an Asus Xtion Pro (without RGB) do the job (direct Depth --> Laser conversion) or do i have to have RGB too for that to work?